# How do I print all the files older than 10 days containing particular string?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, find

I have tried this but not working.

```
find . -mtime +10 -print| grep -H -r "test" | cut -d: -f1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `xargs` and process the files found by `find`, but `find` alone can make it:

```
find . -mtime +10 -exec grep -l "test" {} \+
```

- `find ... -exec XXX {} \;` (or `\+`, [thanks Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19862979/how-do-i-print-all-the-files-older-than-10-days-containing-particular-string#comment29543229_19863064)) performs the XXX command on the files found by `find`.
- `grep -l` just shows the name of the files, as I think you are trying to get with `cut -d: -f1`.

You may also need to add `-type f` to just find files, no directories.

Comment: Better to end the `-exec` with `+` to minimize invocations.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute using xargs like:

```
find . -mtime +10 -print0 | xargs -0 grep -H -r "test" | cut -d: -f1
```

**edit**

I inserted options so that you won't have problems with spaces in the filenames.